# How to pass hidden value from jQuery to Spring MVC controller without Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following table

```
    <table id="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
               ...
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${not empty userList}">
                    <c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input name="id" value="${user.id}" hidden></td>
                            ...
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:when>
            </c:choose>
            </tbody>
        </table>
<input type="button" name="objects"/>
```

and here is my javascript to select row in my table

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#table tr").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        var elem = $(this).find('td:first input').attr('value');
    });

    $('.objects').on('click', function (e) {
        alert($("#table tr.selected td:first input").attr('value'));
    });
});
```

When I select row and then press button `objects` I get an alert of selected id. I'd like to pass this id in Spring MVC controller, desirable without Ajax.

So I want select user in table, then press button `objects` and pass id of selected user to the new page `/userObjects`. Can you help me with this, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your `alert` and just do something like :

```
var id = $("#table tr.selected td:first input").attr('value');
window.location = '/userObjects?id=' + id;
```

You may have to adapt the `window.location` depending on the url on which you want to forward your user.